# highcharts issue with tooltip and formatter with min:0 on yaxis

Tags: highcharts

No tooltip is shown if shared is false!!!
If i change the min to null it shows the tooltip!

In the previous highcharts this issue doesn't exist

```
$(function () {
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'

        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            startOnTick: false
        },
        tooltip: {
                crosshairs: [true,true],
                formatter: function() {
                    return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
                        '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b>';
                }
            },

        series: [{
            data:[[1345593599999,null],[1345593600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345594200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345594800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345595400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345596000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345596600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345597200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345597800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345598400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345599000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345599600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345600200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345600800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345601400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345602000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345602600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345603200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345603800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345604400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345605000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345605600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345606200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345606800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345607400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345608000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345608600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345609200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345609800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345610400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345611000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345611600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345612200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345612800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345613400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345614000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345614600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345615200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345615800000,0.0010000000474975],[1345616400000,0.0010000000474975],[1345617000000,0.0010000000474975],[1345617600000,0.0010000000474975],[1345618200000,0.0010000000474975],[1345618800000,-2147483.75],[1345619400000,-1073741.625],[1345620000000,0.39273166656494],[1345620600000,0.56872498989105],[1345621200000,0.82007998228073],[1345621800000,1.2374949455261],[1345622400000,1.8156150579453],[1345623000000,2.515278339386],[1345623600000,3.2450299263],[1345624200000,4.0675683021545],[1345624800000,5.0065865516663],[1345625400000,5.9605016708374],[1345626000000,6.8903851509094],[1345626600000,7.8542332649231],[1345627200000,8.8226404190063],[1345627800000,9.7728967666626],[1345628400000,10.693440437317],[1345628400001,null],[1345679999001,null]]
        }]
    });
});​
```

Comment: can you reproduce the issue @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hBbdj/ ?  Seems to be working. And why are you using nulls `[1345593599999,null]`?

Comment: please use chrome not firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your values are negative, hence setting min to 0 takes them out of view, that seems to be breaking the tooltip, if i remove the two negative values it works. Why do u have negative values? esp when u are setting min to 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/hBbdj/2/

Comment: I just want the query from the database not to extinguish if i want non negative values... i want javascript to do that for me!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hBbdj/3/ i just reduced the magnitude of the negative values and it works now. I am not sure why this is happening, but it is because of the highly negative values. May be a bug in highchart